# Can I use Restricted Boltzmann Machine for multiple regression output

Tags: regression, rbm

My question - Can we apply RBM in predicting multiple output regression like predicting course scores for a student, price of several product that a customer buys?

So I was dealing with multiple output regression problem!

I came across a paper where they had predicted GPA Scores for students in different courses using Restricted Boltzmann Machine (RBM). However, the paper did note detail about the how RBM was implemented for the problem of multiple regression output!

Please note that since I was planning to develop a single model for the task...I landed up here, I do not want multiple models!